# Trying to restore user in graph and get 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to try out deleting and restoring a user in graph. I deleted the user by sending a delete to https://graph.microsoft.com/Beta/users/{id} and verified they showed up in deleted items at /beta/directory/deleteditems

When I send a post to: /Beta/directory/deleteditems/{ID}/restore - I get the response (415) unsupported media type.

Is delete and restore fully working for users in beta yet, or is there something wrong with my process?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this Ryan.  I was able to reproduce this issue **if** I don't set a `Content-Type` header in the request.  If I set `Content-Type: application/json` then the restore does indeed work.

I'll report this to our team.